# Calculate Login time interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider below DDL & DML :

```
CREATE TABLE `EventLog` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `actiontype` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `executiondate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO EventLog (actiontype,executiondate)
values
('LOGIN','2014-09-12 12:34:37'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-12 12:58:37'),
('LOGIN','2014-09-12 13:12:25'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-12 14:25:37'),
('LOGIN','2014-09-12 16:45:00'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-12 18:00:31'),
('LOGIN','2014-09-12 20:05:37'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-12 20:34:37'),
('LOGIN','2014-09-13 02:15:10'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-13 03:05:22'),
('LOGIN','2014-09-13 06:10:45'),
('LOGOUT','2014-09-12 08:34:37');
```

Now I want to calculate Login time interval.
For example I have **start date-time --> 2014-09-12 12:44:37** and **end date-time --> 2014-09-12 12:59:37**. Here a user logged into system at 2014-09-12 12:59:37, but our input start date-time is greater than it. So consider the input start date-time. Same in end date-time, Here input end date-time is greater than logged out date-time (check in mysql table data - 2014-09-12 12:59:37), then consider logged out date-time.

As per this logic, for this scenario, output will be **14 Min**.
This is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dbdb4c/1) for practice.
Thanks in advance

**Edit :** Latest [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a4d57) with username column.

Comment: I think is missing a user column, without it you can assume that the next record after Login is a Logout. Try with this `SELECT 
    a.Id "A ID"
   ,b.Id "B ID"
   ,a.ActionType "A Action"
   ,b.ActionTYpe "B Action"
   ,a.ExecutionDate "A ExecutionDate"
   ,b.ExecutionDate "B ExecutionDate"
   ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a.executiondate, b.executiondate) "Time"
FROM EventLog a inner join EventLog b
where (a.id + 1) = b.id
and a.ActionType = 'LOGIN'`

Comment: This is not as per my logic, read question again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 SELECT ins.id, outs.id, logindate, logoutdate,
      (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logoutdate) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(logindate)) / 60 AS LoginTime_mins
 FROM
      (select id, executiondate as logindate from EventLog where actiontype = 'LOGIN') as ins
 JOIN
      (select id, executiondate as logoutdate from EventLog where actiontype = 'LOGOUT') as outs
 ON ins.id = outs.id -1
```

Comment: I appreciate your work, but I haven't mentioned userloginId here. There will be multiple records for multiple users. So last condition will now work.